# sql column formatting

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting

Just a quick question to ask

In MySQL how would I display numeric values as string equivilents?

So

```
1 = New
2 = Old
3 = Cancelled
```

So if I had somehting like

```
SELECT object_name, object_status where object_status > 0
```

and this returned

```
object#1, 1
object#2, 2
object#3, 1
object#4, 3
```

But I wanted it to display

```
object#1, New
object#2, Old
object#3, New
object#4, Cancelled
```

Thanks in advance KS

Comment: You would be best improving your modal and creating a mapping table. Then you would only need to join rather than slowing the query down with case statements and such.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `CASE` on this,

```
SELECT object_name,         
        CASE object_status 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'New'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Old'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Cancelled'
            ELSE NULL
        END status
where object_status > 0
```

or

```
SELECT object_name,         
        CASE 
            WHEN object_status = 1 THEN 'New'
            WHEN object_status = 2 THEN 'Old'
            WHEN object_status = 3 THEN 'Cancelled'
            ELSE NULL
        END status
where object_status > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT object_name, 
 case object_status when 1 then 'New' 
  when 2 then 'Old' 
  when 3 then 'Cancelled' end as status
from myTable
where object_status > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new mapping table and join the two tables together. The new table would have 2 columns - a column for `object_status`, and a column for the nice name. Then just join the two.

```
SELECT s.object_name, sm.StatusName
FROM Status s
INNER JOIN StatusMapping sm on s.object_status = sm.object_status
WHERE s.object_status > 0
```

This would allow you to add new mappings as needed without changing your query.